# Getting error : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. , while posting my website comments to twitter. Using C#

Tags: c#, twitter

Am trying to post my website comments on my twitter wall, but i am getting an error

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

My tried code is as :-

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Dotned.UI.Framework
{
public class TwitterClient
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Exception Error { get; set; }
    private string _twitterUpdateUrl = "http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json";

    public TwitterClient(string userName, string password)
    {
        this.Username = userName;
        this.Password = password;
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(_twitterUpdateUrl);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.Username, this.Password);

            SetRequestParams(request);

            string post = string.Format("status={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message));

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
                {
                    writer.Write(post);
                }
            }

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            string content;

            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Error = ex;
        }
    }

    private static void SetRequestParams(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        request.Timeout = 50000;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    }

}
}
```

The process is getting break at  `WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();`.

Any suggestions are highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You must authenticate with OAuth. You can either visit Twitter's [OAuth Page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) to see how to write this yourself or visit their [3rd Party Library Page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries) to find a library to help you.